# How to wait for webpage to finish its work before showing it in an iframe on another web-page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web-page which contains an IFrame. In that iframe, I am supposed to display a graph rendered from the data collected. The rendering is done by a JavaScript file and then a web-page in loaded. Now, the problem is that the rendering can take some time to finish if input data to JS file is large. Now, when I use the main web-page for to display the graph in an iframe then it shows me the old web-page (not the new one which is developed by JS file with new data).

```
//This is the body of web-page to be displayed in the iframe. The last script added here renders the data to display graph
<body>
    <div id="graph">
    </div>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/viz.js@1.8.0/viz.js" type="javascript/worker"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-graphviz@1.3.1/build/d3-graphviz.min.js"></script>
<!--    <script src="./renderer.js"></script> -->
    <script src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/renderer.js"></script> 
</body>
```

```
//This is the iframe in which the above page is to be displayed
<iframe id='svg_frame' src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/render.html">
</iframe>
```

**EDIT ---**
Here is the JS file used for rendering:

```
var testStringShort="d78097e9b6812ac3d37bf34f06d230c7|Jenny||teaches||Samir|\nc2a399e13af9dbadc41b7b967a1deb95|Jenny||teaches||Swadesh|\nda14b3e11e7621846e493db4bea4ae64|Jenny||teaches||Sargun|\nd18032aa6345478915e0aaaee95cd5f2|Jenny||teaches||Sahil|\nd8c015ebdc812f0ad36cd18a5536d317|Jenny||teaches||Kavya|\n70fd4bc59f00f8931818a11e719d8872|Jenny||teaches||Shalvi|"
var NODE_COLOR='#fd153c'
var graphviz = d3.select("#graph")
    .graphviz()
    .logEvents(true)
    .on("initEnd", render);

var n_nodes=0,n_edges=0;

function render(filename) {
    graphviz
    var dot=getDOTfromGDF(filename);
    console.log('DOT OBTAINED')
    graphviz
        .renderDot(dot);
}
function getLabel(string)
{
    if(string.indexOf('/')==-1)return string;
    return string.split('/').pop()
}
function randomColor()
{
    return '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
}
function randomColorString(string)
{
    var hash = 0, i, chr;
    if (string.length === 0) return hash;
    for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        chr   = string.charCodeAt(i);
        hash  = ((hash << 5) - hash) + chr;
        hash |= 0; // Convert to 32bit integer
    }
    hash = hash & 0xFFFFFF;
    return '#'+hash.toString(16);
}
//DOT documentation: https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:center
function getDOTfromGDF(filename) {
    //read file
    var dotArray=[]
    dotArray.push('digraph G {')
    dotArray.push('node [style="filled"];')
    dotArray.push('size = "16.66,8.33!";') // 1200x600 at 72px/in, "!" to force
    dotArray.push('ratio = "fill";')
    dotArray.push('center = "true";')
    dotArray.push('bgcolor="#64F0F0";')
    /*const fs = require('fs') 
    fs.readFile(filename, 'ascii', (err, data) => { 
        if (err) throw err; 
        var lines=data.toString().split("\n") 
        console.log(lines)
    })*/
    var lines=testStringShort.toString().split("\n")
    var nodes=[]
    var edge_description=[]
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; ++i) {
          lines[i] = lines[i].trim()
          var words=lines[i].split('|')
          //Add node to nodes if not already added along with label
          nodes.push(getLabel(words[1]));
          //nodes.push(getLabel(words[3]));
          nodes.push(getLabel(words[5]));
          //Add edge_description
          var label=getLabel(words[3])
          var QUERY_URL='/../?type=Search&Subject=?&Predicate='+label+'&ObjecT=?&shapes=svg'
          edge_description.push(getLabel(words[1])+' -> '+getLabel(words[5])+'['+'label="'+getLabel(words[3])+'", color="'+randomColorString(getLabel(words[1]))+'", URL="'+QUERY_URL+'", target= "_parent"];')
          n_edges++;
       }
    new Set(nodes).forEach(function(value1,value2,set){
        var label=getLabel(value1)
        n_nodes++;
        var QUERY_URL='/../?type=Search&Subject='+label+'&Predicate=?&ObjecT=?&shapes=svg'
        dotArray.push(label+' [ '+'label="'+label+'", fillcolor="'+randomColor()+'", URL="'+QUERY_URL+'", target= "_parent"];')
    })
    dotArray=dotArray.concat(edge_description);
    dotArray.push('}')
    console.log(n_nodes) 
    console.log(n_edges)
    var dot = dotArray.join('');
    return dot
}
```

I want the whole graph to be rendered by the javascript and then displayed in the iframe.

Comment: You need to make some callback function when it's done. Why in iframe?

Comment: @FlashThunder. I am new to JS. How to make callback functions? Actually, I have to display the data in its raw form too. Hence, I am using a radio button to display a single web-page in the iframe out of the 2 made. If I can use anything else, please suggest.

Comment: You need to give more information about what and how it's being rendered (the render script)

Comment: Ok. I am editing the question

Comment: If I didn't get what you mean, please comment my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the problem is not in the rendering JS file. The nodejs server that I coded, was actually picking the old file instead of waiting for my bash script to generate my new file.
Hence closing the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<iframe id="svg_frame" style="display:none;" src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/render.html">
</iframe>

....


var graphviz = d3.select("#graph")
    .graphviz()
    .logEvents(true)
    .on("initEnd",render)
    .on("end",showIframe);

function showIframe(){
   window.parent.document.getElementById('svg_frame').style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: there is probably something wrong with your rendering, can you check the console for errors?

Comment: The Iframe is in the HTML file for main web-page and the renderer.js script is included only in the web-page which is being displayed in the Iframe. Code block 1 is the only page where renderer.js is included. May be this is the problem??

Comment: Yes, it is a problem then... I mean the scope from parent frame doesn't affect the inner frame. Inner frame doesn't even see that code until you will tell it to see in `d3.select("#graph")` , should be something like `$('#graph', frames['svg_frame'].document)`

Comment: I have checked the web-page I get by the rendering. It appears correct. But I can't see that page on the Iframe. Probably, style.display remains none only.

Comment: add `console.log('show!!!');` to `showIframe` function, you will see if it shoots the `end` event at all

Comment: showIframe() is not being executed. No console output